# how to change the parent location window when successfully checking using jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem in my code. I make a simple form using the checkbox. when the checkbox is clicked, the data will be validated. then if validation is successful then the checkbox will still be checked and window.location will change, if it fails, the checkbox will be unchecked and window.location will change.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".publish").click(function () {
        var data = $(this).attr("data-identity");
        if ($(this).attr('checked', true)) {
            var url = "/Manager/AdminApprove/";
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: url + data
        }).done(function (data) { //refresh after click
            $(document).change(function () { 
                if ($(".publish").prop('checked', true)) { //if data succes validation
                    var error_succes = "Succes";
                }
                else {
                    var error_succes = "Error";
                }
                window.parent.location = "/Manager/Admin?" + error_succes;
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: try location.href = your_url and let me know what you get.
And alos why you are using document change inside done method ?
data will be returned from the server

Comment: @pawankumar : the url that I get is manager/admin. So, what should I do? help

Comment: do location.href = "manager/admin?data="+error_succes;
try using this

Comment: @pawankumar  the url that I get is manager/admin. still the same

Comment: url cannot change

Comment: I think u shoudl check what's in data remove document on change from done method.
and from server side send data . in if condition check what is in data (if you are sending sending true on success and false for failer you can check that in if else and decide what to do).
check below example
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076009/confused-on-jquery-ajax-done-function

Comment: @pawankumar thanks, very helpful

Comment: then upvote the comments and post the actual answer so other people can find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var error_succes = "";
            if (data == "True"){
                var error_succes = "Succes";
            }
            else {
                var error_succes = "Error";
            }
            window.parent.location = "/Manager/Admin?" + error_succes;
```