# jQuery AJAX call initiates without command when .done function added

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm rewriting a series of jQuery AJAX requests and have been having trouble with `.done` code blocks.  I'm attempting to send an AJAX request and wait for the response before processing the data.  As a guide, I have been using the following page:
http://michaelsoriano.com/working-with-jquerys-ajax-promises-and-deferred-objects/

I've also looked at countless stack questions to try and troubleshoot my issues, but haven't found anything which has helped.  For reference, some of the questions I've looked at are below:
[jQuery Ajax call not processing .done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31285085/jquery-ajax-call-not-processing-done)
[jquery ajax done function not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744066/jquery-ajax-done-function-not-firing)
[Confused on jquery .ajax .done() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076009/confused-on-jquery-ajax-done-function)

I've noticed that when I create code blocks which are similar to the guide above, the functions run on page load, rather than when they are triggered in code.  To isolate the fault, I created a simple example, as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="getData()">Click me</button>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
//Commented out due comment below   
/*function getData() {
        console.log('enter getData');
        return $.ajax({url:'./testajax.html',type:"POST"});
    }
     
    getData().done(function(data){
        console.log('enter done');
        alert(data);
    });*/

    function getData() {
        console.log('enter getData');
        $.ajax({ url: './testajax.html', type: "POST" })
            .done(function (data) {
                console.log('enter done');
                alert(data);
            });
        alert('after');
    }
</script>

</html>
```

I was expecting that when my example page loaded, nothing would happen, as there was no trigger to execute the `getData()` function unless the button was clicked.  However, when I load the page, my console logs 'enter getData' and then 'enter done', and I get an alert with the contents of my `./testajax.html` page (just a single string).  Further, when I then click the button, it enters `getData()` but doesn't trigger the `getData().done` function, so no alert is received.

Is anyone able to guide me on the right track here and help me prevent the `getData()` function from executing on page load, and instead make the button click execute the AJAX request, wait for the result, then execute the code in the `.done` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getData()` expression you have immediately calls the function on pageload. Then you attach a `.done` handler to it.

It sounds like you want a function that calls `$.ajax` *and* attaches `.done` to it, like:

```
function getData() {
    console.log('enter getData');
    $.ajax({ url: './testajax.html', type: "POST" })
        .done(function (data) {
            console.log('enter done');
            alert(data);
        });
}
```

Then attach `getData` as an event handler somewhere.

[Don't use inline handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice). Use `.addEventListener` or jQuery's `.on('click'` instead.

Comment: Thanks @certainperformance, that has fixed the problem of code execution on page load, but the timing of the execution is still off.  I've updated the question to include an `alert('after');`, which currently fires *before* the `alert(data);` line.  Is there a way to make it wait until the AJAX request has finished before continuing code execution?  I could nest everything inside successive `.done` functions but I'm looking for a cleaner approach.

Comment: You need to to embrace the asynchronous nature of JS - don't be afraid of using it. No, there's no good way to block further code from running until the request is complete. One approach is to use functions: `getData().then(processData)` where `processData` is completely synchronous